# NSURLConnection delegate and populating table view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have to make a call to NSURLConnection and have the following delegate:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    [connection release];

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData  
        encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [responseData release];

    results = [NSArray array];
    results = [responseString JSONValue];
        NSLog(@"Number of rows: %d", [results count]);
}

//table view number of rows    
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        //return [_userInfo.friendsInfo count];
        NSLog(@"Number of rows: %d", [results count]);
        return [results count];
    }
```

As you can see I tried to print out the number of entries in the array and I got 5 when inside the delegate for NSURLConnection and 0 inside the tableView numberOfRowsInSection.
I would like to use the data that I got from the NSURLConnection to populate the table. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two potential problems:

1. You are missing a retain. The line "results = [NSArray array];" is pointless, and you should retain the the JSONValue as "results = [[responseString JSONValue] retain];" (remember to release at some point!)
2. Also, are you reloading the tableView after you get the data? You should do something like [table reloadData]; or [self.tableView reloadData]; depending on your class structure.

Answer (score 1):

Are you retaining the array that results points to?  I think you need to call `setResults` (if it is synthesized) or explicitly retain.